# Rest Framework not raising error to react native

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, response

When i send fetch api request to Django backend.

when ever i return this Response:

```
return Response(
    {
        'message': 'Username is already taken'
    }
) , status = status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT
```

But in this case, React native, this method did not catch any error, why?

```
.catch(error_resp => {
    console.warn('error_resp : ')
    console.warn(error_resp)
})
```

Comment: check CORS policy

Comment: this may help: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/